# How do you apply a hotfix using ColdFusion Administrator?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a .jar file that I need to apply to my ColdFusion server. The instructions say to:

"Open the ColdFusion Administrator and apply the provided hf800-1875.jar hot fix using the System Information page."

Where is the System Information page? I am logged into ColdFusion Administrator on that server and I don't know where to go.

Answer (score 3):

Please see this screenshot ([fullsize](https://dl.getdropbox.com/u/2495797/img/0911/cf8-system-information.png)):

[image: cf8-shot]

Comment: Click the i in the blue circle in the upper right to get the the system info page.